# Proof that If $A$ is regular matrix then $S$ is bijective.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in Mn$ and $S: Mn \to Mn$ be linear mapping such that $S(T)=AT$. Proof that if $A$ is regular then $S$ is bijection. I am intersed if there are any logical errors in my proof.

My proof:

Contraposition: "$S$ is not bijective if $A$ is not regular matrix."

Then by negation it goes: "$S$ is not bijective and $A$ is regular matrix."

Then it is enough to find counterexample for negation. Let $A$ be identity matrix. $A$ is obviously regular so

$\forall X\in Mn$ $\hspace{1 mm}$$S(X)=AX=IX=X$ $\implies S$ is bijective. That is in contradiction with assumption that S is not bijective. So negation is not true that implies that if $A$ is regular then $S$ is bijection.

$\hspace{150 mm}\square$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

You want to prove this: for each $A\in M_n$, if $A$ is regular, then $S$ is bijective. This is the same thing as asserting that, for each $A\in M_n$, if $S$ is not bijective, then $A$ is not regular. And the negation if this statement is: there is *some* $A\in M_n$ such that $S$ is not bijective and $A$ is regular. Simply showing that, if you take $A=\operatorname{Id}$, then $S$ is bijective and $A$ is regular will not prove this.

Another why of seeing why your argument doesn't work is this: define a new product in $M_n$ by$$M\odot N=\begin{cases}N&\text{ if }M=\operatorname{Id}\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Define $S^*(T)=A\odot T$. The statement “if $A$ is regular, then $S^*$ is a bijection” is false. But your argument still works!